# How to find a match that the given id matches with the document that consist it in its an array of Id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongodb. I would like to get back all documents, which consist of an array of id,  that match with my ID provided.

This is the scheme of my Doc. It represents a "Post". In its "likeBy" field, this contains all the users who liked the post before.

Given that I have a user' ID, with this DB, I would like to get back all Doc in which this ID have liked before

[image]

In mongo shell, this can be done by find {likeBy:ObjectId('61eebfa4742ee001699cb504')}

But with mongoose, nothing has return.

This is what I have tried

```
const ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId;

 Post.aggregate([
      {
        $match: { likeBy: ObjectId(userId) }
      }

    ])
      .then((posts) => res.send(posts))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.sendStatus(400);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Types } from 'mongoose';   

 Post.aggregate([
      {
        $match: { likeBy: Types.ObjectId(userId) }
      }

    ])
      .then((posts) => res.send(posts))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.sendStatus(400);
      });
```

when you use mongoose you have to use its own default types

Comment: Since I use module.exports = {} to export function ; 
And got such error-> 
import { Types } from 'mongoose';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module;  Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: const Types = require("mongoose").Types